# Wifi sometimes not working

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, thinkpad

this bug is bothering me since xubuntu 14.04 (currently running xubuntu 16.04).
Sometimes my network manager can't login to my wifi. When this happens i need to restart my Router and then the network manager can login again. However after some time has passed it doesnt work again and so on. It's not a wifi Problem because the other devices in my house work normally (chromecast, Windows 10 machines, Android,iPhone etc. ). My Router is a "Fritzbox 6360 cable" and the machine iam running xubuntu on is a thinkpad wifi a Intel wireless card. If you need more Information iam more than happy to give those.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too since the upgrade to v16.04 LTS. As to where it comes from, I couldn't possibly comment but I don't remember it being an issue with 14.04

You can get the network manager up and running again without rebooting by going into the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and typing the following commands:

```
   sudo ifconfig eth0 up
   sudo dhclient eth0
```

then:

```
   exit
```

to close the terminal screen.

Not a solution or a permanent fix but a worthy work-around not requiring a reboot which might be inconvenient.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. It looks more like that the fritzbox is rejecting my Xubuntu machine. The network manager starts fine.